# Rails 3 Finding A Child's Grandparent Through It's Other Parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

How does one query for lateral grandparent in Ruby on Rails?

For instance I have the following models setup:

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :registrations
end
```

**Registration**

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :competition
end
```

**Competition**

```
class Competition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :registrations
  belongs_to :tournament
end
```

**Tournament**

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :competitions
end
```

So what I want to do is find all **Users** who have **Registrations** belonging to a particular **Tournament**. The only way I know of to do this is by finding all users, looping through each of them and then querying each users individual registrations like so...

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <% if user.registrations..joins(:competition).where("competitions.tournament_id = #{params[:tournament]}").count > 0 %>
        print out user information...
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This seems like a real half-youknowwhat way of doing things because I'm selecting records that I don't need, can anybody suggest a better more Railsy way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step I would take to create a more "Railsy" solution would be to move the query logic out of the view and into the model layer.  You could add these two queries to your Tournament model:

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :competitions

  def registrations
    regs = []
    self.competitions.each do |competition|
      competition.registrations.each do |registration|
        regs << registration
      end
    end
    regs
  end

  def users
    usrs = []
    self.registrations.each do |registration|
      usrs << registration.user
    end
    usrs
  end

end
```

Now within a view you can:

```
<% @tournament.users.each do |user| %>
  User: <%= user.name %><br />
<% end %>
```

You also have a method that returns all the registrations in a tournament, should you ever need it.  Hope this helps you see another approach.

Comment: Hi Don, thank you for your reply. I tried your code but the users method returns this error message: `undefined method `user' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000005030700>`. I think it's because Competitions have many registrations.

Comment: Yes, I think your are right.  I modified the code so that each of the Competition's registrations are added to the 'regs' array individually (rather than an array of registrations.)  You should be able to access 'user' for an individual registration record.

Comment: One question though - this is kind of extra, but not crucial (I'll open a new question if need be). Your solution returns an array, is there any chance we can return a relation instead so I apply additional constraints on the returned users?

Comment: I'm not good enough at ActiveRecord queries to tell you how to get the results back as a relation.  I asked a related question a while back around how to sort the results in the array.  The answer that I got from @DGM showed how to manipulate the array.  (You may look at Ruby array methods to see if you can do what yo want that way.)  He also gave me an example of how to achieve what I wanted via a DB query.  That portion of the answer may help you bypass the array approach:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847855/rails-3-how-can-you-sort-an-ar-query-result-by-doing-math-on-attributes

Comment: I think I'll settle for the array for now and when the times comes for expansion I'll figure out how to turn this into a query.

Comment: This is awesome - what a great technique.